# Disable mouseover when idle but background is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div which is containing a table in which u can select rows using up/down arrow and using mouse(mousemove/mouseout). On up/down i am scrolling div which have fix height. Problem starts when I use up/down to select rows, at the same time if pointer is also pointing to table, the row which has pointer focus, getting selected every time because of scroller i think. :(

mouseover and mousemove-->

```
$("body").delegate(".item-search-result tr","mouseover",function(){
        $(".item-detail").removeClass("tr-active");
        $(this).addClass("tr-active");           
    });
    $("body").delegate(".item-search-result tr","mouseout",function(){         
        $(this).removeClass("tr-active");        
    });

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {   
    currFormRow = parseInt($("#HfCurrRow").val());
    if(currDetailIndex!=-1){
    newIndex = --currDetailIndex;
    $(".item-detail).removeClass("tr-active");
    $(".td_detail_"+currFormRow).addClass("tr-active");
    }

  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    currFormRow = parseInt($("#HfCurrRow").val());
    if(currDetailIndex<($("#item-searchresult_"+currFormRow).children("tr").length)-1){
          newIndex = ++currDetailIndex;
         $(".item-detail).removeClass("tr-active");
         $(".td_detail_"+currFormRow).addClass("tr-active");
    }
  }
   $("#HfCurrRow").val(currFormRow);
});
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: line 2 double quotes missing for selector `$(".item-detail").removeClass("tr-active");`

Comment: I see `delegate`, Which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: @Satpal code is working fine. I edited my code to give some hint about my problem. Problem is in the functionality. Btw version is 1.10.2